# Vagrant failed permissions with nfs only when mounting to apache folders

Tags: vagrant, nfs, centos6, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint as Host and CentOS as guest, whenever i am trying to share a folder to an apache folder (example below) it fails and all other apache actions fail to.

```rb
config.vm.share_folder "apache", "/var/www/html", "../src", :extra => 'dmode=775,fmode=775', :nfs => (FFI::Platform::IS_WINDOWS ? false: true)
```

I get following error then:

```
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /var/www/html: cpio: chown failed - Operation not permitted
```

However, when i mount the folder to lets say /html, there is not a single problem and my vagrant runs clean.

I am desperatly trying to get things in the folders they are meant to be, any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

here we've having some kind of this problem too.

The way it worked here was to adjust the syntax of nfs exporting to:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :nfs => { :mount_options =>  ["dmode=777","fmode=777"] }
```

as stated in [26710386](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26710386)

note the :nfs line and mount options. You must to use it as

```
nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"] }
```

and not as the latter way type: "nfs", mount_options: ... was.

Hope it helps.